# Is it correct to say "Compete in our contest!"?

Tags: grammar

I'm wondering if saying "Compete in our contest!" is correct, because usually people say "Take part in our contest", am I right?

The problem is that "Take part in our contest" has too many characters.

Comment: "Come compete in our contest!" sounds natural to me, so I would say so

Answer (score -1):

- Participate in our contest.
- Join our contest.
- Enter our contest.

Comment: What's your opinion about "Compete in our contest"?

Comment: Compete sounds more compatible with a competition where one needs to prove oneself and oust other competitors/ opponents to claim a big reward.
A contest is a bit more light-hearted than a competition and would require people to either enter/join or participate.

Comment: @starfish: your distinction between a competition and a contest wholly relies on how serious a participant engages in it, which is subjective and has no bearing on what the hosts call their event. It's equally valid to say "enter/join the competition", so I see no reason to exclude "compete in the contest". I'd agree with you that there are subtle nuances between the two, but that's not the same as saying it's wrong.